# Em IDE BlueJ Class Random, limitar os valores iniciais e finais

Tags: java, random

Como tenho no codigo dá-me o erro de

> void cannot be deferenced

Na parte do `nextInt()` nas duas ultimas linhas e com tantas tentativas que já fiz acabei acabou por ficar assim. A latitude não pode estar fora de [-9.5,-6.2] graus e a longitude [36.8,42.2]

```
Random randomLongitude = new Random(); 
Random randomLatitude= new Random();
randomLatitude.setSeed((long)-9.5).nextInt((int)-6.2);        
randomLongitude.setSeed((long)36.8).nextInt((int)42.2);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro que lhe dá é porque o método `setSeed` é `void` e por isso não devolve nenhum valor o que faz com que não possa fazer `.nextInt()` de seguida sobre o `void`.

```
randomLatitude.setSeed((long)-9.5).nextInt((int)-6.2);
//---------------------------------^ aqui
```

Este método `setSeed` serve para definir o ponto de inicio randomico, também chamado de semente randomica. É util apenas quando quer poder reproduzir determinadas saídas aleatórias de forma determinística. No seu caso também não precisa de criar dois objetos `Random` pois com apenas um pode gerar quantos números aleatórios quiser.

Se pretende que os números saiam num intervalo especifico necessita de multiplicar o número que sai por `máximo-minimo` e a isso somar o `minimo`:

```
Random random = new Random(); 
double randomLongitude = random.nextDouble() * (42.2-36.8) + 36.8;
```

Analisando esta ultima linha vemos que:

- É gerado um numero no intervalo `[0,1)` com o `nextDouble`.
- Esse numero é multiplicado por `42.2-36.8` que dá `5.4`, dando assim um numero no intervalo `[0-5.4)`
- Ao somar o minimo de `36.8` ficamos com o intervalo de `[36.8, 42.2)`

Pode até criar uma função para simplificar:

```
static Random random = new Random();

public static double aleatorioEntre(double min, double max){
    return random.nextDouble() * (max-min) + min;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double randomLatitude = aleatorioEntre(-9.5, -6.2);
    double randomLongitude = aleatorioEntre(36.8, 42.2);
}
```

[Veja este exemplo a funcionar no Ideone](https://ideone.com/l7ZK3S)